# How to find the USB device if WinUsb endpoint is not available - in UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, usb, registry, printers

I could connect to the USB devices in UWP app according to the instructions in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.usb.usbdevice?view=winrt-20348#examples) via WinUsb endpoint.
I am trying to communicate with a printer using the endpoints. So if the WinUSB is endpoint is not available i need to communicate through REST, SCAN or PRINT endpoints. How we can communicate with the USB device other than the WinUsb endpoint.

Any help would be appreciated.

Working on .Net standard applications and I was trying to create the rest interface path from the registry. But am getting some errors like below,

Comment: Could you please take a look at [Print from your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/print-from-your-app). It shows how to print via Printing API.